# Car can't start after rocker gasket change

Tags: engine, bmw, diesel, gasket

I have a 2008 BMW 120d LCI with N47 engine. Recently was diagnosed with some oil leak on the rocker gasket near the injector area. Were advised to change the rocker gasket seals. So I did change the gasket and after changing and refitting the common rail, high pressure fuel pipe, injectors, head cover etc... The engine wont start, it does crank but just wont fire up. One should mention the car starts and drives perfectly fine before gasket change...

We hook it up with the BMW INPA diagnostic and the DDE was given 3 error memory.

4A64 Gluhkerze Zylinder 1. Ansteuerung

4A44 Gluhkerze Zylinder 3. Ansteuerung

3EC0 Nockenwellensensor, Signal

After some translations: 
3EC0 was the camshaft position sensor
4A64, 4A44 was the Glow plug cylinder 1 and 3, driving(triggering?)

We are confident that the camshaft position sensor did plug back in as all connectors are connected, not sure on glow plug as we never removed or even touch the glow plug on the respective cylinders.

**Hex key for 4A64 were:**

```
4A 64 21 00 00 00 FF 28 48 A6 00 00 40 00 00 00

40 77 AC 02 00 00 00 3A EF 0C 00 0C 2B 0C 12 00

00 80 10 00 01 45 00 5C 51 EA 06 60 71 23 1B 31

42 8B B1 10 00 00 4F 48 F2 8B 0F 0C 2C 3E 27 00

00 00 10 00 01 50 00 37
```

**Hex key for 4A44 were:**

```
4A 44 61 00 00 00 FF 28 48 BD 09 B4 65 4D 3E 56

49 91 B0 10 13 47 4E 3F EE 76 28 0C 2C 80 34 00

00 00 10 00 01 4C 02 4A 51 EB 00 00 3A 00 00 00

41 77 AF 80 00 00 00 3B EF 0C 00 0C 2B 64 12 00

00 80 10 00 01 44 00 5A
```

**Hex key for 3EC0 were:**

```
3E C0 21 00 00 00 01 28 51 EB 01 EB 3A 00 59 52

41 64 AF 08 00 00 3B 3A 7F 0C 00 0C 2B 64 12 00

00 80 10 00 01 43 00 79
```

Please could somebody shed some light on this matter?

Many thanks

Comment: If you reset the errors, do they come back again?  Is there a procedure for  bleeding air out of the fuel lines after dissasembly?

Comment: I reset those error and they dont come back again. Still I am unable to start the engine... That's a good question on bleeding air out fuel lines, i need to take a look at haynes book and BMW TIS

Comment: I think @HandyHowie is on to something and it sounds like you haven't done it after reassembly. Not all diesels need to be bled, but the ones which do *absolutely need it*.

Comment: Found out i need to spray some brake cleaner into the intake to prime the engine, many thanks guys

Comment: If you fixed this, please write what you did and select your answer as *the* answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP responded in the comments and stated the fix.  He primed the motor with carb spray to get it going.  Perhaps it had a mechanical fuel pump or needed the fuel rail primed in some way.

**OP's response as the fix in comments below**

> Found out i need to spray some brake cleaner into the intake to prime the engine